# Pagination shows Same posts

Tags: plugins, php, templates

I made a custom template and I want to show all posts from certain category in this template excluding some ,I am  getting as per desired but pagination shows same posts whether I am on 1st page or second ,is there anything wrong with this template

any help would be highly appreciated

`

```
<?php /* Template Name: Blog Template */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
$homepageLayout = get_theme_mod('homepageLayout', 'no-sidebar');

?>

<div class="container pm-containerPadding-top-110 pm-containerPadding-bottom-90">
    <div class="row">

        <?php if($homepageLayout === 'no-sidebar') { ?>

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">




                <?php
$query = new WP_Query('cat=106,93,138,136,86,23,103,83,84,92,78,137');


 if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

                <?php }//end of posts ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                     <p><?php _e('No posts were found.', 'medicallinktheme'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?> 

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'pagination' ); ?>

            </div>

        <?php } else if($homepageLayout === 'right-sidebar') {?>

            <!-- Retrive right sidebar post template -->
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">

                <?php
$query = new WP_Query('cat=106,93,138,136,86,23,103,83,84,92,78,137');



 if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

                <?php }//end of posts ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                     <p><?php _e('No posts were found.', 'medicallinktheme'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>  

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'pagination' ); ?>

            </div>

             <!-- Right Sidebar -->
             <?php get_sidebar('home'); ?>
             <!-- /Right Sidebar -->

        <?php } else if($homepageLayout === 'left-sidebar') { ?>

             <!-- Left Sidebar -->
             <?php get_sidebar('home'); ?>
             <!-- /Left Sidebar -->

            <!-- Retrive right sidebar post template -->
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">

                <?php
$query = new WP_Query('cat=106,93,138,136,86,23,103,83,84,92,78,137');



 if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

                <?php }//end of posts ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                     <p><?php _e('No posts were found.', 'medicallinktheme'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?> 

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'pagination' ); ?>

            </div>

        <?php } else {//default full width layout ?>

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

<?php

$query = new WP_Query('cat=106,93,138,136,86,23,103,83,84,92,78,137');



 if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

                <?php }//end of posts ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                     <p><?php _e('No posts were found.', 'medicallinktheme'); ?></p>
                <?php } ?> 

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'pagination' ); ?>

            </div>

        <?php }  ?>

    </div> <!-- /row -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

`

Comment: [This will help](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

Answer (score 1):

This made it work. Thanks Milo for link

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'paged'          => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'cat'            => '106,93,138,136,86,23,103,83,84,92,78,137' 
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

?>
```